# XPath: get everything between two empty nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I need to write a xpath expr to get everything (nodes and text) between an empty node (**pb**) and the next occurrence of **pb**.

I can get "everything" after a **pb** node until the end of the XML file with this query:

```
 //pb/following::*|//pb/following::text()
```

But I want to group the "single" results by pb to next pb.

Example:

```
...
<pb/>
<elementX>text here </elementX>     --|
<moreElements/>                       |    Group 1
Plain text here without element     --|
<pb/>
<elementY>text here </elementY>     --|    Group 2
...                                 --|
<pb/>
...                                 --|    Group 3
EOF                                 --|
```

So I want everything between 2 *pb*'s and group it. For this example there should be 3 result groups. All elements from the first *pb* until the second should be in the 1st group. From second *pb* until third *pb* is the second group. And from the third *pb* until the end there should be the third group.

Hard to describe in words. Need any further infos?

How to tell xpath where to end and group the results?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create groups, XPath won’t be sufficient (because the result will always be a flat sequence). An XQuery 1.0 solution looks as follows:

```
for $pb in //pb
let $next-pb := $pb/following-sibling::pb[1]
return element group {
  $pb/following-sibling::node()[empty($next-pb) or . << $next-pb]
}
```

If your processor supports XQuery 3.0, you can use the more efficient window clause:

```
declare context item := document {
  <xml>
    <pb/>
    <elementX>text here </elementX>
    <moreElements/>
    Plain text here without element
    <pb/>
    <elementY>text here </elementY>
    ...
    <pb/>
    x
  </xml>
};
for tumbling window $w in /xml/node()
    start $s when name($s) = 'pb'
    end $e when name(head($e/following-sibling::node())) = 'pb'
return element group { tail($w) }
```

Comment: Thank you Christian. The XQuery 3.0 is sadly not working... did you test it? I guess I have to learn more about the xquery language. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I did (I used BaseX). Which processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Saxon. (HE/PE/EE 9.8.0.9)

Comment: Thanks. I’ve just tried Saxon (HE 9.8.0.6J and EE 9.8.0.12J), with success; the query result is identical to BaseX. Can you give me some more details on what “not working” means in your case?

Comment: Thank you for testing. sorry for being so unspecific in my first comment... the "request" delivers an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian points out, XPath can only deliver a node-set (or node sequence), so there's no way of doing any grouping. It's also tricky (but not impossible) to deliver the nodes between two milestone tags `<start/>` and `<end/>`. In XPath 1.0 you can do:

```
start/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::end]
```

but it's likely to be very inefficient with a long input sequence. Solutions using XQuery windows or XSLT grouping are much more satisfactory.